# Сообщение "No input file specified." при попытке запуска php скриптов из под phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, localhost

На машине Windows 10 x64 ничего не установлено кроме

- **PhpStorm** 2016.1.2(x64)
- **PHP 7**  (распакован архив в С/php)

При попытке запуска php скриптов из среды, открывается браузер с сообщением *No input file specified:*[image: No input file specified]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

[Это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947405/phpstorm-built-in-web-server-doesnt-work-with-php-and-cause-no-input-file-spec) не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое сообщение *No input file specified* выдаёт интерпретатор PHP, когда его запускают без указания/неверно указанным путем к php файлу.

PhpStorm по-умолчанию создает проекты в личной папке пользователя windows. Многие пользователи имеют имена **с символами отличными от латиницы**, как я, например, в данном случае: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А интерпретатор не дружит с символами, на которые заменяются русские буквы при "перелинковке".

**Решение:**

Создать проект с путем, состоящим только из латинских символов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]